# Laravel: Storing users in repository after retrieved from db for less MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, laravel

Is there an established way of storing models that you may want to handle in memory/cache instead of going to the database?

I have models with `created_by` and `updated_by` columns which are stored as integers of the `User`'s id. I also usually display on the frontend the name of the person who created each model.

Say that the logged in user has the same `id` as the `created_by` column. I will always check the logged in user for authentication but I shouldn't need to query the database twice to also display the created user's name when sending the json response back...

I am having way too many duplicate queries getting the same exact user and it is slowing the application down.

Is this a good use case for a method in a `UserRepository`? I have not used repositories yet but wondered if anyone else has had this problem and came up with a good solution.

Here is an example of places that multiple users may be queried:

```
// CompanyController.php
public function update(Request $request, Company $company)
{
    // got user with ID = 1 here
    $user = Auth::user();

    if(!$user->can('update', $company)){
        return response(403); //deny user
    }

    $company->fill($request->all());
    $company->save();

    // got user with ID = 1 here again...
    // this model was created by the logged in user
    return response()->json($company->with('created_user'));
}

// App\Company.php
public function created_user()
{
    // get the user identified by ID in the created_by column
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'created_by');
}
```

I am on Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.2

Comment: Can you post some of the methods out of your user controller so we can see some context into how you are already leveraging Laravel to manage your data?  It's hard for me to imagine using Laravel without leveraging Eloquent, which, in itself is a "repository."  I'm guessing you just want to leverage a cache, which can also be leveraged several ways depending on what you're trying to accomplish.  Some of that will also be exposed by revealing some of your code.

Comment: By repository I mean something like [this](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository). I added an example situation to my OP where it would get the same user twice from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did not have much time to write my own repositories for each model and I found https://github.com/AuthentikCanada/eloquent-cache/ package which is pretty easy to use. You simply add a trait to your models and it starts caching your queries.

Comment: I would suggest shedding some light on what you're trying to accomplish before jumping into installing a new caching library...  Laravel has some built-in caching tools that might be a better fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @yogurt will try and install and see how it goes

Comment: @MichaelMiller was my OP not explanatory enough? The main problem is that there are repeat queries that are running and I want to use some sort of in-memory or cache solution to not run duplicate queries in MySQL. If it cuts down the queries by half or even a quarter I will be happy.

Comment: Fair enough...  Have you looked at the tools that are baked into Laravel already?  You're essentially increasing the maintenance time and placing a bet that this library will continue to be maintained by using it...

Comment: Jumping the gun on a new library without looking at what's already available makes it seem like the next issue that you'll have to deal with is an unnecessarily large dependency set.

Comment: But ultimately, it's up to you.  It just seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a Cache facade that can wrap a few different cache drivers (memcache or Redis can both be easily set up).

Here's memcache example of config/cache.php:

```
'memcached' => [
    [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 11211,
        'weight' => 100
   ],
],
```

To store something:

```
cache(['key' => 'value'], $minutes);
```

To retrieve something:

```
$item = cache('key');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is very generic. I am aware of the Cache facade but I would have to build out an entire Repository trait to catch everything in cache every time I retrieve a model from db and vice-versa get from cache if Eloquent is trying to find a model that was already queried. I was wondering if there is already a solution to this problem that is built for hooking up to Eloquent.

Comment: Nope.  Using the Facade removes the requirements of having to use the repository trait.

Comment: Then how could I use it in the SubstitueBindings middleware? Or each time I do: `User::find(1)`? I would want the `find` function to first check cache for an existing version of that model.

Comment: Ah, yes, you'd have check the cache each time before doing the query without the trait.   Something I'd be more willing to do than add another 3rd party dependency which could lose support any moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have had fair bit of confusion few years back myself after looking at the queries Laravel does for `users` table and `sessions`, `cache` tables if you have setup database drives for them.

It's framework lifecycle footprint which needs to have this data to function properly.

However, if you check, these queries take like like 1-2 milliseconds max. I have had project in which I had huuge amount of users, still honestly these queries never affected performance as those use primary keys for selection (mostly id).

I would suggest you to evaluate `taking down query time of a 2-3 millisecond query down to 1 millisecond` vs `managing and maintaining an extra mid-layer cache service`.

Now, if you want to implement an intermediate caching layer to minimise load from MySQL, then there are native options of laravel `cache` available which can hold/cache your collection forever or for certain time period. If you want more powerful capabilities then you can try for `elasticsearch` or `redis`.

I would still emphasize on the fact that, adding a mid-layer caching layer is an architectural change which would come with maintenance time and an overhead of data sync. Please make sure you have a solid fall-back mechanism if you are using any service outside Laravel, so that if the service is down, you can load the data from MySQL directly.

Comment: Thanks Mihir, it's not just the users table, it's about 12 different tables. So I believe I am above the threshold where it will be faster to grab from cache instead of running over 2,000 queries for saving an order with a bunch of attachments, that are mostly repeated data being saved. I originally wrote it that way so I didn't need to duplicate code but now we are running into speed problems. Would like to be able to use existing code in a faster way, and have made as many database optimizations as possible including all foreign keys and indexes being set.